# Disable sorting for QTreeWidgetItem children

Tags: qt, sorting

I have 1 top level QTreeWidget which has multiple QTreeWidgetItem children. Each QTreeWidgetItem in turn has 4 QTreeWidgetItem children.
I want to sort the QTreeWidgetItem children alphabetically but not the grandchildren.

In my GUI application, ui->taskDisplayTreeWidget is the QTreeWidget .
When I do ui->taskDisplayTreeWidget->sortByColumn(0, Qt::AscendingOrder), sorting is done recursively i.e sorting is applied to grandchildren as well. How can I disable the sorting for grandchildren and perform a different custom sorting for them ?

Comment: Try to sort by yourself with  [QTreeWidgetItemIterator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitemiterator.html#IteratorFlag-enum) you can iterate all the top level items with the flag `QTreeWidgetItemIterator::NoChildren`

Comment: That will be cumbersome

Comment: Create a special subclass of `QTreeWidgetItem` for the grandchildren, and reimplement the less than operator to always return `false`.

Comment: That should work. Thanks!